# South/East Florida tree to help identify

Tags: identification, trees

The rest of the neighborhood has [southern live oak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_virginiana), but this one house has this tree. It doesn't have pointed leaves like some other Southern Florida tree identification requests ([one](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/5462/14277), [two](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/8191/14277)).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess so far is a [Florida Black Olive tree](http://www.floridagardener.com/pom/bucida.htm), or *Bucida buceras*.

(*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucida_buceras)*)

[image]